# SOQL to get records between past 2 months and next 2 months from today

Tags: soql

for eg. today is 2nd may 2022. I need to get records from 2nd march to 2nd july. i need a query that i can run in salesforce workbench. I tried below query

```sql
SELECT EndDate, Id 
FROM ServiceContract 
WHERE EndDate >= LAST_N_MONTHS:2 AND EndDate <= NEXT_N_MONTHS:2 
ORDER BY EndDate
```

but this is returning me records from 1st of the month irrespective of current date. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the LAST/NEXT_N_MONTHS for this, because they work on months, not days. This [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) describes all your possible options. Unfortunately, the best you can really do is use LAST_N_DAYS and NEXT_N_DAYS, which means you'll have to manually calculate that somehow.

Comment: the problem is i will have to perform this query regularly for eg: sometimes for last 6 months to next 12 months so calculating number of days every time is a concern.

Comment: @mahithapaluri for custom ranges, you need to build the date somehow. Without knowing how you plan on calling this, I can't be more specific. For example, in Apex, you can use the date method addMonths. Most other languages have similar capabilities.